# Cordova sharing plugin does not share message on facebook

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I'm using the cordova share plugin to share something on my facebook profile. I need to share a link, with a message and an image. But for now I am willing to share a message and I can never do it. Nothing appears. This works for me for twitter and whatsapp but not for facebook. why?

```
var text="any text";
var image_gif="" //image gif of my cellphone 
var link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana"
 $cordovaSocialSharing.shareViaFacebook(text, image_gif,link).then(function(result) {
    // Success!
    }, function(err) {
    alert("problem")
 });
```

I am using android device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the plugin. Read [plugins documentation](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#web-share-api).

> Facebook Android: sharing a message is not possible. You can share
>   either a link or an image (not both), but a description can not be
>   prefilled. See this Facebook issue which they won't solve. As an
>   alternative you can use shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint since
>   plugin version 4.3.4. See below for details. Also note that sharing a
>   URL on a non standard domain (like .fail) may not work on Android.
>   Make sure you test this. You can use a link shortener to workaround
>   this issue.
>
> Facebook iOS: message, image (other filetypes are not supported),
>   link. Beware that since a Fb update in April 2015 sharing a prefilled
>   message is no longer possible when the Fb app is installed (like
>   Android), see #344. Alternative: use
>   shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint.

Comment: Unfortunately, its unexpected behaviour of this plugin on different devices.

Comment: I hope this answer helped you. Let me know.