# Why Social Sharing plugin sends Image but not text on facebook in Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, facebook-social-plugins

Hello i am trying to use Social Sharing in Ionic 5 to share content from my app to facebook

i installed these

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing
```

.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.url ="www.myproject.com";
   this.imgurl= this.Details.image_path;
   this.message= this.Details.message;
   this.text = this.Details.title;
 }

ShareFacebook(){
this.socialSharing.shareViaFacebookWithPasteMessageHint(this.text, this.imgurl, null /* url */, 'MY project!')
}
```

.html

```
 <ion-button color="primary" (click)="ShareFacebook()"><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></ion-button>
```

Works it sends the image but it doesn't send the text only image. want to send a variable as text.

any hint?

Comment: maybe ```this.text``` is empty.. console.log it and verify first

Comment: no its not empty. I wish it was that simple. IT WORKS ON Twitter and email and sms but on Facebook

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45319571/5909026

Comment: Thanks Najam. I thought so too. But i was hoping for a workaround. Thanks man